Change date picker type (Sliced Invoices)
How might it be possible to change the date picker style? One of the other fields on the same page of this WP extension displays a more comprehensive picker. Please see below.
I am comfortable making changes to this extensions php files directly, but a function.php snippet would be even better as it wouldn't require me to 're-patch' after updating.

When I inspect the element in Chrome, these are the results for the first date picker and then the more desirable date picker:
    .sliced .cmb2-postbox input[type="text"], .sliced .cmb2-postbox input[type="number"], .sliced .cmb2-postbox textarea, .sliced .cmb2-postbox select {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.07);
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #32373c;
    outline: 0;
    transition: 50ms border-color ease-in-out;
    line-height: normal;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    min-height: 29px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
.sliced .repeatable input[type="text"], .sliced .repeatable textarea, .sliced .repeatable select {
    padding: 3px 5px !important;
}
.cmb2-wrap input.cmb2-text-small, .cmb2-wrap input.cmb2-timepicker {
    width: 100px;
}
.cmb2-wrap input, .cmb2-wrap textarea {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.meta-box-sortables input {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
input[type=date], input[type=datetime-local], input[type=datetime], input[type=email], input[type=month], input[type=number], input[type=password], input[type=search], input[type=tel], input[type=text], input[type=time], input[type=url], input[type=week] {
    padding: 0 8px;
    line-height: 2;
    min-height: 30px;
}
input[type=color], input[type=date], input[type=datetime-local], input[type=datetime], input[type=email], input[type=month], input[type=number], input[type=password], input[type=search], input[type=tel], input[type=text], input[type=time], input[type=url], input[type=week], select, textarea {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #8c8f94;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #2c3338;
}
input, select {
    margin: 0 1px;
}
input, textarea {
    font-size: 14px;
}
button, input, select, textarea {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
}
user agent stylesheet
input[type="text" i] {
    padding-block: 1px;
    padding-inline: 2px;
}
user agent stylesheet
input:not([type="file" i], [type="image" i], [type="checkbox" i], [type="radio" i]) {
}
user agent stylesheet
input {
    font-style: ;
    font-variant-ligatures: ;
    font-variant-caps: ;
    font-variant-numeric: ;
    font-variant-east-asian: ;
    font-variant-alternates: ;
    font-variant-position: ;
    font-weight: ;
    font-stretch: ;
    font-size: ;
    font-family: ;
    font-optical-sizing: ;
    font-kerning: ;
    font-feature-settings: ;
    font-variation-settings: ;
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: fieldtext;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: start;
    appearance: auto;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    cursor: text;
    background-color: field;
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 1px 0px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: light-dark(rgb(118, 118, 118), rgb(133, 133, 133));
    border-image: initial;
    padding-block: 1px;
    padding-inline: 2px;
}
.cmb-type-group .cmb-td, .cmb2-postbox .cmb-td {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1.3;
}
.cmb-td {
    line-height: 1.3;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.postbox .inside {
    padding: 0 12px 12px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.postbox, .stuffbox {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1;
}
.form-table, .form-table td, .form-table td p, .form-table th {
    font-size: 14px;
}
.form-table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-top: .5em;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}
#wpwrap {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
body {
    background: #f0f0f1;
    color: #3c434a;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    min-width: 600px;
}
html {
    --wp-admin--admin-bar--height: 32px;
    scroll-padding-top: var(--wp-admin--admin-bar--height);
}

And the better picker:
#side-sortables .cmb2-wrap input[type=text]:not(.wp-color-picker), .inner-sidebar .cmb2-wrap input[type=text]:not(.wp-color-picker) {
    width: 100%;
}
.sliced .cmb2-postbox input[type="text"], .sliced .cmb2-postbox input[type="number"], .sliced .cmb2-postbox textarea, .sliced .cmb2-postbox select {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.07);
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #32373c;
    outline: 0;
    transition: 50ms border-color ease-in-out;
    line-height: normal;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    min-height: 29px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
.cmb2-wrap input, .cmb2-wrap textarea {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.meta-box-sortables input {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
input[type=date], input[type=datetime-local], input[type=datetime], input[type=email], input[type=month], input[type=number], input[type=password], input[type=search], input[type=tel], input[type=text], input[type=time], input[type=url], input[type=week] {
    padding: 0 8px;
    line-height: 2;
    min-height: 30px;
}
input[type=color], input[type=date], input[type=datetime-local], input[type=datetime], input[type=email], input[type=month], input[type=number], input[type=password], input[type=search], input[type=tel], input[type=text], input[type=time], input[type=url], input[type=week], select, textarea {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #8c8f94;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #2c3338;
}
.regular-text {
    width: 25em;
}
input, select {
    margin: 0 1px;
}
input, textarea {
    font-size: 14px;
}
button, input, select, textarea {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
}
user agent stylesheet
input[type="text" i] {
    padding-block: 1px;
    padding-inline: 2px;
}
user agent stylesheet
input:not([type="file" i], [type="image" i], [type="checkbox" i], [type="radio" i]) {
}
user agent stylesheet
input {
    font-style: ;
    font-variant-ligatures: ;
    font-variant-caps: ;
    font-variant-numeric: ;
    font-variant-east-asian: ;
    font-variant-alternates: ;
    font-variant-position: ;
    font-weight: ;
    font-stretch: ;
    font-size: ;
    font-family: ;
    font-optical-sizing: ;
    font-kerning: ;
    font-feature-settings: ;
    font-variation-settings: ;
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: fieldtext;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: start;
    appearance: auto;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    cursor: text;
    background-color: field;
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 1px 0px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: light-dark(rgb(118, 118, 118), rgb(133, 133, 133));
    border-image: initial;
    padding-block: 1px;
    padding-inline: 2px;
}
.cmb-type-group .cmb-td, .cmb2-postbox .cmb-td {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1.3;
}
.cmb-td {
    line-height: 1.3;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.form-table, .form-table td, .form-table td p, .form-table th {
    font-size: 14px;
}
.form-table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-top: .5em;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}
.postbox .inside {
    padding: 0 12px 12px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.postbox, .stuffbox {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1;
}
#wpwrap {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
body {
    background: #f0f0f1;
    color: #3c434a;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    min-width: 600px;
}
html {
    --wp-admin--admin-bar--height: 32px;
    scroll-padding-top: var(--wp-admin--admin-bar--height);
}


Are both datepickers from the same Add-On/Extension/Plugin?  If they are you should submit this to their dev team because they really should get them matching.

Hi Tony,
Yes, they are literally on the same page (as shown in the video). I have reported it, but it's a low priority I'd guess.
Do you know how to unify them?

You'd have to copy over the CSS from the first one and use that to target the second one and then load that CSS into your admin in hopes of overriding the existing one.

Thanks Tony. Which are the specific parts that would need to be replaced and replaced with what?

You'd have to look at the CSS rules that make the appearance look different and then apply those rules to the classes and elements where appropriate.  This is detail oriented stuff that you'll have to work through yourself.

If I knew what to look for, @TonyDjukic, I wouldn't have posted here.
